# Could a species develop its civilization if it wasn't violent?

Tags: civilization, genetics

The race I'm designing originated in a small island in the middle of an ocean the size of Crete, which has no natural predators. That, combained with a random mutation that occured in this species genes in the past, has made them completely peacefull. Now my quiestion is, could a mutation in genes or a lack of predators make a species completely lack violence? If yes, then could that species develop civilization?

Note: They don't conpletely lack violence, but they're way less violent that us humans.

Comment: Is this a sentient humanoid species?

Comment: Do you need a complete lack of violence, or a low-violence society like that of [Bonobos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonobo) would be sufficient?

Comment: More importantly, I'm pretty dubious that a species can live on "a small island in the middle of an ocean" for "**millions of years**".

Comment: You have posted very similar questions short ago https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120761/30492 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120438/30492

Comment: Whatever Crete is, it is not a *small* island. It has an area of 8300 sq. km (3200 sq. miles).

Comment: Of course. As long as there's some natueal way of limiting population growth. Perhaps some sort of voluntary birth control.

Comment: @AlexP -- I took it to mean the ocean was the size of Crete. That would be a pretty small ocean indeed!

Comment: We've been asked quasi-utopian questions like this before.  Have you done your homework?  Those aspects of our nature that make us violent also allow us to take risks, to sacrifice to save lives, to serve and protect (to coin a phrase).  How will you judge the best answer?  What makes "they're driven by a powreful religious belief" better than "they have a hive mind disallowing intraspecies violence"?  If only your opinion makes a distinction, then the question is POB.

Comment: Can you define "completely lack violence" for us?  We've fielded this kind of question before, and the answer usually revolves around how extraordinarily difficult that phrase is.  For example, we have very little experience with creatures that lack an immune system -- you'd be *astonished* how violent immune systems are.

Comment: Pain, misery and hard conditions are what forged humanity to what it became today. Take away the winter, which is a time of potential starvation and the punishment of those who did *not* plan ahead months or even years into the future, and Europeans wouldn't have the genetic demand for relatively high intelligence. Without that, the chances for technological development would have been significantly less. Without that, the quality of life wouldn't have been raised way above the point what would occur without winters. Well, guess that's something to think about for me...

Answer (score 4):

A non-violent species has to be herbivorous, since a carnivorous lifestyle requires violence against prey. The problem is that plant matter contains much less nutrients than meat, so the chance of a completely herbivorous species evolving to have a big brain is quite small.

It's true that humans *today* can survive as vegetarians, but only because we cook our food (to make nutrients easier extractable) and have a network of global trade to provide us with a huge diversity of plants and produce that wouldn't be available on an isolated island.

It takes intelligence to be able to utilize fire to cook food. Your species might never evolve a complex enough brain to take this nessecary step towards higher intelligence. Maybe the sweet fruits of a tropical island could provide enough nutrients, but then you're still missing the incentive to evolve.

A life without enemies and with energy-rich food available at all times would hinder evolution rather than advance it.

If a creature can sleep without fear of being killed, wake up without fear of not finding enough food to fill its stomach, be lazy without fear of any dire consequences, **why should it invest energy into developing a big brain**?

Answer (score 1):

The species are herbivores.  They eat grass.  Like Richard suggests, they have a plant-drug that acts for birth control.  They prefer mates that exhibit intelligence, and build structures for shelter.  Perhaps your island suffers from severe storms.  Gradually the structures and tools used grow more complex.  You have a civilization.  With no predators, they have no need for violence.  Animals are violently territorial when another species encroaches.  Think of hippos.  The other thought is competition and removal of pests.  Your best off making no competing species or pests that can kill your species. This species evolved from herd-animals.

It's easier if they are only peaceful towards their own kind.  Species like this actually exist.  Many ants don't fight members of their own colony.  Your creatures could have herds of cattle or catch fishes but not use violence against themselves.